# Does class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") working on current versions of Netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have been following several tutorials on YT on how to connect NetBeans with XAMPP and it seems like all the posted videos are older versions of NetBeans.

Whenever I use the Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); on my command line it shows up with an error of `"Class.forName()" should not load JDBC 4.0+ drivers` unlike theirs which shows no errors.

Is there an alternative for this command on the current version of NetBeans?

And I can't seem to connect my NetBeans on XAMPP no matter what methods I follow from the internet.

Comment: Yep, nothing to do with NB.  `Class.forName` has not been needed for years

Answer (score 3):

`Class.forName` to load the driver hasn't been neccessary for 15 years. Whatever book or tutorial got you there, you *might* want to consider tossing it in the trash and finding something a little bit more up to date.

However, you've made another mistake: You've misjudged what you're looking at. The message `"Class.forName()" should not load JDBC 4.0+ drivers` **is not an error**. It is sonarcube warning. (sonarcube is a linting tool: It finds aspects of your code that are definitely or likely bugged or otherwise almost universally derided as bad style and tells you about it).

You should not ignore these warnings - they are pointing at places in your code that are either broken, or will likely break in the future, or are likely to lead to problems (that's what 'bad code style' is: Code that is hard to maintain or otherwise likely to cause unneccessary hardship in the near future).

The fix is trivial. Just ditch the line. Whenever you open a connection, the JDBC system will automatically just figure it out, as long as the driver is on the classpath. You don't have to 'load it' like this.

Comment: Further explanation: In modern Java, all available [JDBC drivers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) are automatically registered with the JVM via Java’s [*Service Provider Interface (SPI)*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface).

Comment: _"hasn't been neccessary for 15 years"_. That is not entirely accurate, if the driver is not on the initial classpath you will still need to load it explicitly like this (e.g. if the driver is included in the WAR on Tomcat).

Comment: Thank you for all the information you've given, this has all been helpful to me. I will work on this.